# Convert path with chinese characters in batch file to short path (8.3 chars)

Tags: windows, batch-file, filepath

I have a path such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\My Corporation\例如路徑\測試.txt`.

I want to get the shortname (8.3 chars) from the long name above in a batch file and store it in order to use it in various places in my script. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work! Just replace BatchFile with your path.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set BatchFile=%~f0
set BatchFileDir=%~dp0
for %%x in ("%BatchFile%") do set File83Name=%%~fsx

echo File83Name = %File83Name%
```